# spring boot + spring data rest: post json null value in column "first_name" violates not-null constraint

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-rest, lombok

I use spring boot and **spring data rest** to make a `user`, when I make a POST method for testing like this (use **postman**):

```
{
    "firstName": "Yue",
    "lastName": "Yang",
    "email": "g1enyy0ung@gmail.com",
    "password": "123"
}
```

And the response I receive is:

```
{
  "cause": {
     "cause": {
      "cause": null,
      "message": "ERROR: null value in column \"first_name\" violates      not-null constraint\n  Detail: Failing row contains (2, null, null, null, f, null, null)."
    },
    "message": "could not execute statement"
  },
  "message": "could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [first_name]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement"
}
```

I was very confused about this, I don't know why the *firstName* is null,
here is what I defined the entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "app_user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(columnDefinition = "SERIAL")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String lastName;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "pass")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String password;

    @Getter
    private boolean admin;

    @Column(name = "last_login", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMPTZ")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Getter
    private Date lastLogin;

    public User() {}

    public User(String firstName, String lastName, String email, String password) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }
```

And the SQL is (use **PostgreSQL**, I also use **flyway** to migrate the table when spring boot runs):

```
CREATE TABLE "app_user" (
  id         SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  first_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  last_name  VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  email      VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  admin      BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
  last_login TIMESTAMPTZ,
  pass       VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL
);
```

The hibernate always execute this SQL:

```
Hibernate: insert into app_user (admin, email, first_name, last_login, last_name, pass) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Why is this happening? I search google with this question, but I found almost all searching results use the embed database, like H2.And almost all tutorials don't use the @Column annotation, so is this question related to Hibernate? I am new to Hibernate and spring boot and now I am reading the documentation to find the solution of this question.

I hope someone can help me correct this question.Thanks!

Update: the `application.yml` =>

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/thoughtplus
    username: g1eny0ung
    password: zhuzhu59y
    platform: POSTGRESQL
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: validate
    show-sql: true
  data:
    rest:
      base-path: /api

server:
  port: 8888
```

Comment: do you have getters and setters of all the fields ? you can remove Gettter  and Setter annotations on top of all the fields . when you annotate @Column on top of  fields . implementation provider (Hibernate ) uses persistent fields concept for getting and setting the fields .

Comment: @Barath Wow! thanks, I remove Lombok's annotation, and manually add getter and setter method, and I get the data and post a new JSON data successfully!!! But why Getter and Setter annotations don't being used?

Comment: Can you check the class files ? Does lombok generates getters and setters appropriately ? I am not sure why, I need to try it out. thanks for the thought

Comment: @Barath Thank you mention.I re-add the Getter annotation and check the build decompiled class, the get method generate as I expect.My steps are: First I clean my build, add annotation, then I build once again and check build dir, and the annotation generate get and set method, I re-run the app, I also can get JSON data and post new data. I think my fault is not build again when I change the code.

Comment: And also, the true is when spring boot run, the default configuration will ignore Lombok's annotation. I test it. When I only run the main method the build class doesn't have getter and setter method.Then I clean the build dir and use `Gradle build`, it will successfully generate getter and setter method.@Barath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried using Maven build and faced similar issue.  It got resolved after doing maven build.

I think problem is not with the spring default configuration as I were able to retrieve the entity from the repository successfully. But when I send the entity as a response from the controller, problem is with jackson mapper while converting the entity.

Example :

```
      @GetMapping("/")
        public User getUser() throws JsonProcessingException{
            User user=userSer.getUser(100); 
            System.out.println(user.toString());    
            ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();
            System.out.println("Object mapper "+mapper.writeValueAsString(user));

            return user;
        }
```

Output :

```
User [userId=100, userName=barath]
Object mapper {}
```

GitHub link : [Spring-data-lombok](https://github.com/BarathArivazhagan/Spring-JPA-Hibernate/tree/master/Spring-Data-JPA-lombok)

Answer (score 1):

I test two ways to build class.One is only run spring boot app and will automatically build.The other is manually build use `Gradle build`.

The previous will not generate getter and setter method when I check the decompiled class.

And the second will generate successfully.

I guess it is spring boot default configuration will ignore the Lombok's annotation.

If I am not correct, please let me know and tell me the true reason about this question.

Update: see @Barath answer.